# ¿Como asignarle el tamaño a la base de datos al crearla desde C#?

Tags: c#, sql

Utilizo este `código` para crear una `base de datos` desde `C#` pero quisiera que aparte de asignarle el nombre, asignarle también un tamaño por defecto, he intentado luego del nombre colocarle **Size = valor** pero me dice que hay un error cerca de la palabra `Size`

```
 public void CrearEmpresas(string nombre)
            {
                    using (var conexion = ObtenerConexion())
                    {
                        conexion.Open();
                        using (var comando = new SqlCommand())
                        {                        
                            comando.Connection = conexion;
                            comando.CommandText = "create database " + nombre;                  
                            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
                        }
                    }

            }
```

Estoy usando Sql Server

Comment: Por favor, indica en tu pregunta qué base de datos estás usando. Dependiendo de ello, podrías usar la sintaxis correspondiente. Igual, hay que aclarar que no vas a poder usar inmediatamente la base de datos creada, pues tu conexión actual esta usando _otra_

Comment: @Alfabravo uso sql server

Answer (score -1):

Prueba utilizando el siguiente código

```
"CREATE DATABASE " + nombre+ "
ON
PRIMARY ( 
FILENAME ='c:\\testDatabase\\sqlTest',
NAME ='"+nombre +".mdf',
SIZE = 50MB
) 
GO"
```

La ruta del FILENAME es donde se guardará el archivo, y esta DEBE existir.

Recuerda que esta sentencia se ejecutaría cada vez que ejecutes el método. Si le vas a dar potestad a tu aplicación de crear objetos en la base de datos, la comprobación si los objetos ya existen puede ser engorrosa. Tal vez quieras investigar acerca de Entity Framework y Migraciones.

Puedes encontrar más información acerca del comando Create Database en el siguiente [enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes que es SQL Server?

Comment: Porque utiliza SqlCommand, parte del namespace System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Recuerden siempre agregar un comentario al votar negativamente una respuesta. De esa manera podemos mejorar su calidad.

Comment: Gracias por responder el comentario :)

Comment: @Arriel esa ruta de donde la obtengo?

Comment: La ruta es donde tú quieres que esté el archivo primario de la base de datos. Yo tengo SQLServer2017 y la ruta sería: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA", en mi servidor **local**